# Is it possible to send a variable with my "Go Back" button using href='javascript:history.go(-1)'

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using the following code and would like to send a variable back to the previous page when clicked:

```
echo "<center> Photo #{$Count} | <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back</a></center>"
```

I thought I could do something like this but it doesn't work: I added ?VP='Y'

```
echo "<center> Photo #{$Count} | <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'?VP='Y'>Go Back</a></center>"
```

Comment: no because that uses the browsers history. but as you tagged php- how about sessions

Comment: I figured as much. I do have a session already setup, How would I trigger a session update in my go-back link?

Comment: you would populate the session on page load, and check it when the page was returned to

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just did that and it works perfectly.  I just got stuck trying to have a flag come back with the go back button.  :-)

Comment: I wonder if anything could be done with the history api here.

Comment: server side is the best side, none of the J.S purposed is very robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged PHP, you could do

```
echo "<center> Photo #{$Count} | <a href='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?VP=Y'>Go Back</a></center>";
```

Then on the other page

```
$var = $_GET['VP'];
```

Comment: This worked perfect and gives me ideas for other things I can do.

Comment: @Mdg be very careful with this `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is browser set and completely unreliable

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<a href='' id="back">Go Back</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("back").href = document.referrer + "?variable=value";
</script>
```

Note that document.referrer will be empty if the user navigated to the page directly. Of course thats a problem, why maybe this would be a back up solution:

```
<a href='' id="back">Go Back</a>

<script>
var ref = document.referrer;

if(ref == "") {
    ref = "javascript:history.go(-1);";
} else {
    ref = ref + "?variable=value";
}

document.getElementById("back").href = ref;
 </script>
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Using the Session worked for me, but I was bent on making something come back with the go back button. lol

Comment: Thanks Emil, I tried your first example and it went back to the home page.  I'll look at your 2nd example and Webby's ex. later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using php, so you could solve it by making a simple form with the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as the action and add a hidden field with the value.
Or add a session variable :) `SESSION['yourvar'] = 'whatever'`

Then on the next page you get it using the `$_GET` or `$_POST` from the form or get the session variable by `echo $_SESSION['yourvar']`. When working with sessions make sure you start them at the start of your pages. More details here http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php